# OSGI - Inject bean in new object

Tags: java, dependency-injection, osgi, blueprint-osgi

I may not fully grasp the concept of beans and services but all my researches lead me to nothing.

In my OSGI project, I got a bundle `A` that provide a service (called `myService`).

A bundle `B` consume this service in a bean (called `myBean`) that is also exposed as a service.

Beans and service declaration is done in Blueprint.

For now, both bundle A and B are resolved by Karaf and the wiring is ok.

But my bundle B has another bean (called `myOtherBean`), also exposed as service, that dynamically creates new objects. Those objects (called `MyObject`) must have a reference on the bean `myBean`.

How could I pass the reference?

An easy way would be to put the reference in my bean `myOtherBean` and inject it through the constructor of `MyObject`. But I am wondering if there could be another way to do that. Some suggested to use the `@Inject` annotation in `MyObject` but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think passing the service in the constructor is a good way to do this. Using a factory is possible but if you want to create the object in code it is difficult to use a blueprint factory.
You can do it by injecting the blueprint context and retrieving the object from it manually but this is pretty ugly.

Comment: Injecting the blueprint context is what I want to avoid. Just for information, would it be easier with an other kind of depedency injection API like DS?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in DS. Why is it an issue to create the object using plain java code?

Comment: Actually it's not an issue as you answer my question but I was just wondering for general knowledge if there was any kind of dependency injection API that is able to do that

Comment: Most frameworks allow some kind of factories but they are typically quite limited. So it is quite usual that you need java code.

Comment: In DS you would do this by making "myOtherBean" a prototype service factory. You have to use the latest OSGi Release 6 plus DS 1.3 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a factory pattern and want to inject the created bean into the declared bean. Correct?

If so see: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-osgiblueprint/

```
 <bean id=”accountFactory” class=“org.apache.geronimo.osgi.AccountFactory”>  
       <argument value=”account factory”/>      
   </bean>

   <bean id=”accountThree”
         factory-ref=“accountFactory” 
         factory-method=“createAccount”>   
       <argument value=”3”/>
       <property name=”description” value=”#3 account”/>      
   </bean>
```

Comment: Your solution won't work in my case. I will end with a factory in a bean but my issue is the same. I won't get the bean from my code. To be more precise, I get an undefinied number of objects from a database and for each of those objects, I need to instantiate another type of object which consume a service.